# How do you copy a Struct array to another struct in the same array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I am trying to work through my code, I'm unable to use a sorting algorithm due to crashes caused by trying to copy a structure at a specific array position to another in the same array at a different location.

```
//include statements
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//defines
#define MAX 100
#define STRUCTMAX 26
#define STUDENTS 9

//Struct declarations
typedef struct{
    char street[STRUCTMAX];
    char city[STRUCTMAX];
    char state[STRUCTMAX];
    char zip[STRUCTMAX];
}Address;

typedef struct{
    char firstName[STRUCTMAX];
    char initial[STRUCTMAX];
    char lastName[STRUCTMAX];
    Address adress;
    int age;
    double gpa;
}Student;

//prototypes
void readFile(Student students[]);
void printAll(Student students[]);
void printBestGpaName(Student students[]);
double averageGPA(Student students[]);
void printAboveAverageGPA(Student students[]);
void printYoungestLowGPA(Student students[]);
void sortStruct(Student students[]);
void strSub(char s1 [], char s2 [], int start, int size);
void initialize(Student students[]);

void main(void){
    Student students[STUDENTS];
    readFile(students);
    printAll(students);
    printBestGpaName(students);
    printf("Average G.P.A is %.2lf\n" ,averageGPA(students));
    printAboveAverageGPA(students);
    printYoungestLowGPA(students);
    sortStruct(students);
    printf("\n");
    printAll(students);
}

void readFile(Student students[]){
int i = 0;
char numberValue[10];
char line[MAX];
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(
           "/Users/derekroy/Desktop/Lab_6/Lab_6A/Students.dat", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Students.dat file not found.\n");
    exit(1);
}

while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(line, MAX, fp);

    strSub(line, students[i].firstName, 0, 7);
    strSub(line, students[i].initial, 10, 1);
    strSub(line, students[i].lastName, 11, 9);
    strSub(line, students[i].adress.street, 20, 16);
    strSub(line, students[i].adress.city, 36, 13);
    strSub(line, students[i].adress.state, 49, 2);
    strSub(line, students[i].adress.zip, 52, 5);

    strSub(line, numberValue, 58, 2);
    students[i].age = atoi(numberValue);

    strSub(line, numberValue, 60, 5);
    students[i].gpa = atof(numberValue);

    i++;
    }
}

void printAll(Student students[]){
int i;

printf("All listed Students: \n");

for(i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i){
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s, %s %d %.2lf\n" , students[i].firstName, students[i].initial,
           students[i].lastName, students[i].adress.street, students[i].adress.city,
           students[i].adress.state, students[i].adress.zip, students[i].age, students[i].gpa);
}
printf("\n");
printf("******");
}


void printBestGpaName(Student students[]){
int i, best = 0;

for(i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i){
    if(students[i].gpa > students[best].gpa)
        best = i;
}

printf("Student with best G.P.A: ");
printf("%s %s %s\n" , students[best].firstName, students[best].initial, students[best].lastName);
}

double averageGPA(Student students[]){
int i;
double sum = 0.0;

for(i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i){
    sum += students[i].gpa;
}

return sum / i;
}

void printAboveAverageGPA(Student students[]){
int i;
double average = averageGPA(students);

printf("Students with above average G.P.A: \n");

for(i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i){
    if(students[i].gpa > average)
        printf("%s %s %s\n" , students[i].firstName, students[i].initial, students[i].lastName);
    }
}

void printYoungestLowGPA(Student students[]){
int i, j, young = 1000;
double average = averageGPA(students);

for(i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i){
    if(students[i].gpa < average){
        if(students[i].age < young){
            j = i;
            young = students[i].age;
        }
    }
}

printf("The youngest student with a below average G.P.A: ");
printf("%s %s %s\n" ,students[j].firstName, students[j].initial, students[j].lastName);
}

void sortStruct(Student students[]){
int i, j;
Student temp;

for(i = 1; i < STRUCTMAX; ++i){
    /*temp.firstName = students[i].firstName;
    temp.initial = students[i].initial;
    temp.lastName = students[i].lastName;
    temp.adress.street = students[i].adress.street;
    temp.adress.city = students[i].adress.city;
    temp.adress.state = students[i].adress.state;
    temp.adress.zip = students[i].adress.zip;
    temp.age = students[i].age;
    temp.gpa = students[i].gpa;*/

    temp = students[i];
    j = i - 1;

    while(j >= 0 && temp.gpa < students[j].gpa){
        //students[j+1] = students[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    //students[j+1] = temp;

    }
}

void strSub(char s1 [], char s2 [], int start, int size){
int i;

for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        s2[i] = s1[start];
        start++;
    }
s2[i] = '\0';
}
```

The offending line is in the Sort function.
How can I make this work, and copy the specified structure to their new address in the structure array?

Comment: `students[j+1] = students[j];` is the correct way to copy a struct. A crash indicates that you are accessing out of bounds of your array; so you will need to review the rest of your program.  (Based on the code you have posted so far it's not possible for anyone here to check that, since you didn't include how the function is called or anything).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Hey, thanks for the comment. I added the rest of the program I am working with.

Comment: `while (!feof(fp)) { fgets(line, MAX, fp);` is wrong.  Use `while (fgets(line, MAX, fp) != NULL) {`.  Better: `while (i < STUDENTS && fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {`

Comment: Note: Due to finite precision of `double`  You may want to use a slight offset when doing averages: `if(students[i].gpa > average*1.0000001)`

Comment: `void main` isn't right

Answer (score 2):

you defined only 9 student records

```
Student students[STUDENTS];   -> STUDENTS macro is 9
```

you are iterating till STRUCTMAX which is a macro defined as 26
so you will go out of bounds causing the crash

```
for(i = 1; i < STRUCTMAX; ++i){
```